# get_attribute('xpath') returns None

Tags: python

I am working on an automation project with python 3.9 where I try to scrape a calendar. I was hoping someone could help me convert a relative xpath into all absolute xpaths or maybe find a way to get the xpath by 'get_attribute('xpath').

This is my code:

```
all_spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='calendarCellRegularFuture etmNoBorder']")
for span in all_spans:  
    print(span.get_attribute('xpath'))
```

The terminal then returns this:

```
None
None
None
None
```

I am using Selenium webdriver with Chrome.

Comment: `<span>` elements don't typically have an "xpath" attribute. Show the HTML you're dealing with.

Comment: But when I inspect the element I can copy xpath through the developer tools of chrome.

Comment: And the XPaths of the four spans are `(//span[@class='calendarCellRegularFuture etmNoBorder'])[1]` through `(//span[@class='calendarCellRegularFuture etmNoBorder'])[4]`, among an infinite number of other variants. Not sure what values you expect. There is no "one definitive XPath" to any element, and you should not need machine-generated XPath in the first place. You already have the elements, what else do you need?

Comment: I want the absolute xpath for all the elements in the list. so that I end up with a list of elements.

Comment: You _already have_ a list of elements. It's called `all_spans`.

Comment: Yeah and I want a new list that contains the absolute xpath for all those elements.

Comment: I already gave you one of the options you have, you can generate those paths easily in Python. Also, again, there is no "one definitive XPath" to any element. The number of variants is literally infinite, and what the Chrome developers give you is just one of the many options (and pretty useless overall). Maybe you should explain some more what you intended to do with those XPaths.

Comment: I want to convert a third party calendar into my google calendar with an API, the third party calendar consists of 35 squares of which some contain events and some do not. This is what I use the class for, to check if there is an event. But the element that has that class only contains the time but not the date, to check the date I need to go up a few steps. This is easy to navigate when I have the xpaths because then I only have to change a few variables.

Comment: But you can go up a few steps right in the original XPath, something like `//span[@class='calendarCellRegularFuture etmNoBorder']/ancestor::div[some condition][1]` will select the fist (closest) ancestor `div` that fulfills some condition, and then navigate from there. Another option would be `//div[some condition and .//span[@class='calendarCellRegularFuture etmNoBorder']]` which selects all `div` that fulfill "some condition" and contain one of those `span`s.

Comment: Long story short, I don't think it's useful to try and get automatically generated XPaths of those elements. You already know what elements you're looking for, you already know the HTML structure, there is no need whatsoever to let Chrome generate XPaths for you. Use relative navigation from the elements you already have selected (`find_elements_by_xpath` is available on any element, not just on the `driver`).